# Notifying users of App updates

Tags: ios, app-store

I updated an app in App store. The problem is App store doesn't notify me of the update.
A previous version of that app was installed in my iPad, and I was expecting a notification will be shown regarding the update. I ended up manually searching for the app to update it.

My question is, why isn't it giving me notifications? I assumed that the app store will automatically send notifications about an update, but in our case it didn't happen.

Did I forget to set something while uploading the app? Or should I manually set it while coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get app info for example http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=422876559 and check version

and then do local notification http://www.developers-life.com/local-notification-sample-code-os-4-0-only.html

Comment: So will this put my updated app in the app store's "Updates" section?

Comment: Oh. Well correct me if I'm wrong, but Apple automatically notifies the user of any updates right? Does that mean that my app was somehow "bypassed"? I will accept your answer because it actually notifies the user of any updates. Though I just want to clarify why the App store failed to place my updated app in its "Updates" section.

Comment: y, Apple should automatically notifies. maybe not enough internet connection or something else